# what is the difference between a function defined inside jquery ready block and one outside

Tags: jquery, function

I register a function to a button with onclick attribute, and define this function in $() block(I know it is a bad practice, and it is just an example), when I click the button, an error occurs: Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined. Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    function hello(){
        alert('hello');
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" onclick="hello()"/>
</body>
```

if I put hello function code out of $() block, it works. I know $() is executed when DOM is parsed, when I click the button, the DOM must already has been parsed, so why it reports an error?
Thanks.

Comment: your function named `hello` is scoped to the anonymous function you pass to `$()` so it can't be called from your onclick handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, except that functions *executed* (not defined) inside a `$.ready` block are guaranteed to execute after the DOM is ready to be accessed/manipulated.

Your issue is one of scoping; you've created a local function which isn't accessable at the global scope where your event is being handled.

Answer (score 2):

your code assumes hello is a global function which it is not.

```
$(function(){
    function hello(){
        alert('hello');
    }
    $("#btn").click(hello);
});
```

Comment: window.hello = function(){ will make it global. anyway inline js sucks