# Why am I getting a ReferenceError: not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

i am trying to add jQuery to my page, I am getting this error though: ReferenceError: preview is not defined

I have a js file in the js directory of my theme:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function preview() {
        var hoverhome = 'url("images/Screen2.png") no-repeat';
        var empty = '';
        //home
        $('nav .home a').hover(function() {
            $('.viewport').css('background-image', hoverhome);
        });
        $('nav .home a').onmouseout(function() {
            $('.viewport').css('background-image', empty);
        });
    }
});
```

I have this in my functions file:

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'preview', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scriptfile.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
```

This is in my html head tag:

```
<head> 
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <title><?php wp_title('|','true','right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo(     'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scriptfile.js?     ver=1.7.1'></script>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

and this is in my header to call the function:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
        preview();
     //--><!]]></script>
</div>
```

finally, this is my css:

```
.viewport
{
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
position: relative;
top: -90px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But. I'm getting this error in firebug:

```
ReferenceError: preview is not defined
```

Comment: The preview() function is created after document is ready, so you can't use it in the <script> section. Just use preview() right after you define it, in the document.ready function.

Comment: @Yvette what do I need to check? I don't see a link..

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3773356/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15478041/218196

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `preview` inside a function. That scopes it to that function, so it isn't a global and you can't call it from anywhere other than inside that function.

Get rid of the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
});
```

wrapper. It isn't doing anything useful and it is breaking your code.

You also need to make sure that you define `preview` in either the same script as the one that calls it or an earlier one. (Or you need to delay execution as described below).

Note that if you call `preview` before the elements it touches exist, then it isn't going to do anything. So you also need to make sure that when you call it, you are doing so after they exist. Putting the call directly in the *header* probably won't do that. Move the call to the footer or wrap it in a document.ready event handler (as you are currently doing for the function declaration).

Answer (score 1):

The `preview()` function is called before it is defined. 
The function is defined in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
 ...HERE
}
```

and HERE is executed only after the entire HTML has been loaded.
Remove the `preview()` call, and add it after the definition:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
   function preview()
   {
      var hoverhome = 'url("images/Screen2.png") no-repeat';
      var empty = '';
      //home
      $('nav .home a').hover(function()
      {
        $('.viewport').css('background-image', hoverhome);
      });
      $('nav .home a').onmouseout(function()
      {    
            $('.viewport').css('background-image', empty);
      }); 
   }
   preview();
});
```

Comment: right, the "ReferenceError: preview is not defined" error in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT add

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scriptfile.js?     ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

to your `<head>`.

You should hook your function `add_my_script` like this(you can add the following snippet just after your `add_my_script` function):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

After hooking it to `wp_enqueue_scripts`, WordPress will automatically add your script when it calls `wp_head();` in your header file.

To avoid scoping errors, rmove the `document ready` wrapper:

```
    function preview() {
        //the rest of your code here
    }
```

Call the function after the DOM is ready:
Your code should be like:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      preview();
    });
     //--><!]]></script>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added your code, but have accumulated more errors.

TypeError: $ is not a function and the original error ReferenceError: preview is not defined

Comment: Try replacing the `$` in your preview function by `jQuery`

Comment: Are you sure the file is being included?

Comment: I am not sure, is there a way to check if it is?

Comment: Also, replacing the jQuery with $ only changed the error to another TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: I told you to replace `$` by `jQuery` not the opposite. add an `alert()` in your js file to check if it has been included.